# using SqlFieldsQuery without DB connection

Tags: ignite, gridgain

As part of our junits we do not use db connection but “manually” populating the cache using “put” method - cache.put(someIntegerId, entity). Everything is working as expected except SqlFieldsQuery which return no records (even for 'select * from table'), while using api getAll(ids) shows the expected entities.
I assume, the fact that in the junits populate the cache using "put" method somehow doesn't populate the entry in the table behind (table exists but no records)... Is there a way to bypass this and make SqlFieldsQuery return results (dummy table creation/”sync” cache data/other)? how to make the entries we put in cache to be populated into the ignite cache table?
cache.get(id) / cache.getAll(ids) return the expected results (I assume because its working on the cache maps and not the table)

when working normally (not junit) we have a connection to the DB and everything is working properly including same code dealing with SqlFieldsQuery (*cache configuration we use setQueryEntities(qryEntities)* )
using embedded Ignite, writethrough is off and readthrough is on

THX!!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is completely fine - moreover, it is very common to use KV API to insert data and SQL for reads. So no worries here.

There must be some issue with how you insert the data. I'm 99% sure that the situation is the same as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706752/apache-ignite-select-query-returns-0-records-but-data-exists-in-cache) question. Check it out. Most likely, you have some mismatch between the value type put into the cache and the value type expected by the SQL table.

Comment: Correct! this is the issue im experiencing (i see the log: "pair is not inserted into any SQL table"). the problem is that my production code use A class type in the cache (and so is the CacheConfiguration.indexedTypes while during testing I insert A_Mock type (A_Mock inherits A). I thought the inheritance will work as their are both A type. Any suggestions how to achieve that? i must use mock objects during testing (i cannot produce the actual cache object)